# Cannot access MODIS Download from FTP using Python

Tags: python, modis, ftp, pymodis

I tried to access the FTP site of MODIS data using Python ftplib module but always fail to connect. I am connecting using: ftp = ftplib.FTP("e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov")

here is the error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or establishment connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

However, if I access the ftp site thru my web browser, I was able to connect and download files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are accessing the HTTP archive at [**http**://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/](http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/). `ftplib` is expected to fail when you try to connect to HTTP instead of FTP.

<s>The FTP archive is located at [**ftp**://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/](ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/).</s>

However, both archives do not contain the exact same data. Depending on the MODIS product you are looking for you might find it on the FTP or you might not. The obvious Python choice for accessing the HTTP archive would be `urllib` or `requests`, or you could just use one of the existing Python MODIS modules like [`pymodis`](https://github.com/lucadelu/pyModis).

edit:

As mentioned by Devdatta in the comments, disregard the FTP information post 2018 as this source has been retired.

Comment: Hi @Kersten, why I cannot access the ftp server ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/ tried ftp = FTP(host). host = 'ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/'. The error is gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed. But I can open the ftp site in my browser.

Comment: @user32145 http://stackoverflow.com/a/34282077/4169585

Comment: For those who are looking at this answer post 2018, do note that the FTP server has been retired, and the recommended way is to get the data from `https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check http://www.pymodis.org which is a Free and Open Source Python based library to work with MODIS data.

It offers bulk-download for user selected time ranges, mosaicking of MODIS tiles, and the reprojection from Sinusoidal to other projections, convert HDF format to other formats and the extraction of data quality information.

In the last days a series of updates where applied, also to the related GRASS GIS 7 Addon [r.modis](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.modis.html) which is a toolset to import MODIS satellite data into GRASS GIS.